# Cascading list using custom directive of Angular JS while using json as input

Tags: json, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to implement a custom directive using angular js's custom directive but first drop-down goes unselected and it gives me error saying "Error: 10 $digest() iteration reached. Aborting!
Watcher fired in the last 5 iterations:

index.html goes here -

```
<!doctype html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<html>
<head>
    <title>Adnan Try</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/1.0.7/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cascading.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div ng-app="cascading">
    <div ng-controller="CascadingCtrl">
        <cascading countries = "{
    'India': {
    'Maharashtra': ['Pune', 'Mumbai', 'Nagpur', 'Akola'],
    'Madhya Pradesh': ['Indore', 'Bhopal', 'Jabalpur'],
    'Rajasthan': ['Jaipur', 'Ajmer', 'Jodhpur']
    },
    'USA': {
    'Alabama': ['Montgomery', 'Birmingham'],
    'California': ['Sacramento', 'Fremont'],
    'Illinois': ['Springfield', 'Chicago']
    },
    'Australia': {
    'New South Wales': ['Sydney'],
    'Victoria': ['Melbourne']
    }
    }"
                ></cascading>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

cascading.js file is

```
angular.module('cascading', [])
    .controller('CascadingCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {

    }])
    .directive('cascading', function() {
        return {
            restrict : "E",
            scope : {
                countries : '='
            },
            templateUrl: 'cascading.html',
            link: function($scope, $element, $attribute) {
            }
        };
    });
```

and cascading.html is here

```
<div>
    Country:
    <select id="country" ng-model="states" ng-options="country for (country, states) in countries">
        <option value=''>Select</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div>
    States: <select id="state" ng-disabled="!states" ng-model="cities" ng-options="state for (state,city) in states">
    <option value=''>Select</option></select>
</div>
<div>
    City: <select id="city" ng-disabled="!cities" ng-model="city" ng-options="city for city in cities">
    <option value=''>Select</option></select>
</div>
```

My hunch is i m doing something wrong in cascading.html that leaves angular js in clue less mode about two way binding.

**EDIT**
plnkr link is - `http://plnkr.co/edit/osqXgK6CB1zpcMPfHTO3?p=preview`

Comment: The first thing you should do is use a recent version rather than 1.0.7, which is from May 2013. Then create a plunkr, so that we can play with and fix your code.

Comment: $digest() iteration reached. Aborting!  : The error  normally occurs when you create a loop of changes over a property. For example, like when you watch for changes on a certain property and then change the value of that property on the listener.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.. Just used recent AngularJS and it seems everything is just working.. I used https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js and everything is just working.

PS:
Thanks @JB Nizet for your comment about.

Comment: Even the plnkr you shared is working because you included the latest version.